# Sub-modules of free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I'm going back through basic module theory notes, and I've come across a paragraph explaining that a sub-module of a finitely generated free module may not itself be free. In my course a free module $M$ over $R$ is defined to be one that contains a basis for $M$. A basis must be $R$-linearly independent and any $m\in M$ must be able to be expressed as a finite sum of basis elements.

The lecture notes define the rank of a free module to be the number of elements in a basis for it (which was proved to be the same for any basis). They then state that if N is a submodule of M, then Rank$(N) \leq$ Rank$(M)$. However, they say, a submodule of a free module might not itself be free. They give an example: the module $\mathbb{Z}/ 6\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}/ 6\mathbb{Z}$ is free; the sets $\{1\}$ and $\{5\}$ are both bases, and I think they are the only ones, for any others wouldn't be linearly independent. They consider the submodule generated by $[2]$, and state that it isn't free because it has a cardinality of 3.

I can see that the submodule isn't free by exhaustively trying the possible subsets as bases, but I can't see what this has to do with its cardinality. I feel like I'm missing something important. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A finitely generated $R$-module $M$ is free if $M \cong R^n$ as $R$-modules. If $|M| < |R| < \infty$, then there is no way to have an isomorphism $M \cong R^n$.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to show that the submodule $M$ generated by $[2]$ is not free is to note that
$$
3 \cdot [2] = [0] = 0 \cdot [2].
$$
so $[2]$, the only non-zero element of $M$, is not a basis of $M$.

Comment: "...[2], the only non-zero element of $M$,..." Is $[4]$ not another non-zero element of $M$?

Comment: @Servaes, you're absolutely right, one also has$$
3 \cdot [4] = [0] = 0 \cdot [4].
$$